# Is there a @visibility package concept in PHPDoc / PHPStorm?

Tags: package, visibility, php-5.3, phpdoc, phpstorm

I have a domain model written in PHP, and some of my classes (entities inside an aggregate) have public methods, which should never be called from outside the aggregate.

PHP does not have the *package* visibility concept, so I'm wondering if there is some kind of standardized way to define `@package` and `@visibility package` in the docblocks, and to have a static analysis tool that would report violations of the visibility scope.

I'm currently trying out [PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/), which I've found very good so far, so I'm wondering if this software has support for this feature; if not, do you know any static code analysis tool that would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, PHPStorm does not seem to provide this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The closest parallel to this line of thinking that I see in PHP's capability is using "protected" scope rather than public for these kinds of methods.  Granted, that requires using inheritance to grant access to the protected items.  In my years of managing phpDocumentor, I've never encountered anything else that attempts to mimic that kind of "package scope" that I remember from my Java days.

Comment: When I'm talking about *aggregates*, they are actually composed of several objects, which have to communicate together by their public methods. I'm aware of the limitations of PHP, and not trying to mimic Java really, just trying to hint the PHP code analysis tool so that it could report potential wrong uses of my classes!

Answer (score 0):

If the entities within your aggregate root should not be modifiable without going through the aggregate root, then the only means you have to control that is making the entity a private or protected member so that all modifications to the entity have to go through the aggregate.

```
class RootEntity {
    private $_otherEntity;
    public function DoSomething() {
        $this->_otherEntity->DoSomething();
    }
    public function setOtherEntity( OtherEntity $entity ) {
        $this->_otherEntity = $entity;
    }
}
```

Someone can still always do:

```
$otherEntity = new OtherEntity();
$otherEntity->DoSomethingElse();
$rootEntity->setOtherEntity($otherEntity);
```

Though, I guess you could use the magic __call() method to prohibit setting of the _otherEntity anywhere except during construction.  This falls under total hack category :)

```
class RootEntity {
    private $_otherEntity;
    private $_isLoaded = false;

    public function __call( $method, $args ) {
        $factoryMethod = 'FactoryOnly_'.$method;
        if( !$this->_isLoaded && method_exists($this,$factoryMethod) {
            call_user_func_array(array($this,$factoryMethod),$args
        }
    }
    public function IsLoaded() {
        $this->_isLoaded = true;
    }
    protected function FactoryOnly_setOtherEntity( OtherEntity $otherEntity ) {
        $this->_otherEntity = $otherEntity;
    }
}
```

So, from there, when you build the object, you can call $agg->setOtherEntity($otherEntity) from your factory or repository.  Then when you are done building the object, call IsLoaded().  From there, nobody else will be able to introduce a new OtherEntity into the class and will have to use the publicly available methods on your aggregate.

I'm not sure if you can call that a "good" answer, but it's the only thing I could think of to truly limit access to an entity within an aggregate.

[EDIT]: Also, forgot to mention...the closest for documentation is that there is an @internal for phpdoc:
http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/for-users/tags/internal.html

I doubt that it will modify the IDE's code completion, however.  Though, you could probably make a public function/property but label it as "@access private" with phpdoc to keep it from being in code completion.

Comment: @internal could be the solution, however to date, it's still not supported!